# Error on setting ConnectionInitSql with Hikari Version : 3.4.5

Tags: java, database, maven, junit, hikaricp

I am getting the following error when I upgrade my Hikari version to 3.4.5

```
The configuration of the pool is sealed once started. Use HikariConfigMXBean for runtime changes.
```

I am running the following @BeforeEach test

```
 dataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean().softEvictConnections();
 dataSource.setConnectionInitSql("set search_path to " + getTestSchema() + ", public");
```

This is how I load my DataSource

```
public class DataSource {
  private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
  public static HikariDataSource ds;

  static {
    config.setJdbcUrl(
        System.getProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:123/abc"));
    config.setUsername(System.getProperty("username", "xyz"));
    config.setPassword(System.getProperty("password", "123"));
    ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
  }

  private DataSource() {}

  public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return ds.getConnection();
  }

  public static void evictConnection(Connection connection) {
    ds.evictConnection(connection);
  }
}
```

```
class TestClass extends DatabaseTestCase {
 @Autowired
  private HikariDataSource dataSource;

@BeforeEach
  void initData() throws SQLException {
    DataSource.ds = dataSource;
    dataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean().softEvictConnections();
    dataSource.setConnectionInitSql("set search_path to " + getTestVitmSchema() + ", public");
  }
```

This is how I setSchema for the Test Cases

```
public abstract class DatabaseTestCase {

  private String testSchema;

  @BeforeEach
  final void setupSchema() {
    int classHash = Math.abs(getClass().getSimpleName().hashCode());
    testSchema = String.format("test_%s", classHash);
    Map<String, String> placeholders = new HashMap<>();
    placeholders.put("schema", testSchema);
    placeholders.put("name", "xyz");
    placeholders.put("password", "123");
    placeholders.putAll(getPlaceholderReplacement());
    Flyway flyway =
        Flyway.configure()
            .dataSource(DataSource.ds)
            .schemas(testSchema)
            .placeholders(placeholders)
            .load();
    flyway.migrate();
  }
```

How can I set Connection Init Sql without getting the error. Thank you.

Comment: you need to load datasource differently on test, how you load datasource ? using property or code? can you share sample?

Comment: Updated the question to include the DataSource details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You will need to create a new `dataSource` to do this.  You can see why from looking at the [source code](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/ffd528dbd2d683fd41bc35ed58027cdecdca6c2b/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.java#L375-L379).

Comment: How can I create a datasource just for the test. Can you guide me. Thank you. @Laird Nelson